# How to compare date with unicode date in odoo

Tags: python, datetime, unicode, odoo

I'm trying to compare my selection date and my plan date, this my plane date code :

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
if self.date_plant:
    from_date = self.date_plant
    d1 = datetime.strptime(str(from_date), fmt)
    date_after_month = datetime.date(d1) + relativedelta(months=1)
    cetak = date_after_month.strftime(fmt)
    self.nursery_plandate = cetak
```

This is my code to compare:

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
if self.date:
    fromdt = self.date
    plan = self.nursery_plandate
    rang = int(7)
    d1 = datetime.strptime(str(fromdt), fmt)
    d2 = plan.day
    d3 = d1.day
    if d1 and plan:
        if d1 == plan:
            self.nursery_information = '2'  # pass
        elif d3 < d2:
            self.nursery_information = '0'  # untimely
        elif d3 > d2:
            self.nursery_information = '1'  # late
        else:
            if d3 >= rang:
                self.nursery_information = '1'  # late
            elif d3 <= rang:
                self.nursery_information = '0'  # untimely
            else:
                self.nursery_information = '2'  # late
```

And here is my error:

```
line 166, in dateinformation
d2 = plan.day
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'day'
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.nursery_plandate` is not valid datetime/date object, so you can not access it's properties, you need to create valid datetime object from that value and then you can access it's properties.

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
if self.date:
    fromdt = self.date
    plan = datetime.strptime(str(self.nursery_plandate),fmt)
    rang = int(7)
    d1 = datetime.strptime(str(fromdt), fmt)
    d2 = plan.day
    d3 = d1.day
    if d1 and plan:
        if d1 == plan:
            self.nursery_information = '2'  # pass
        elif d3 < d2:
            self.nursery_information = '0'  # untimely
        elif d3 > d2:
            self.nursery_information = '1'  # late
        else:
            if d3 >= rang:
                self.nursery_information = '1'  # late
            elif d3 <= rang:
                self.nursery_information = '0'  # untimely
            else:
                self.nursery_information = '2'  # late
```